# How to check log level in Redis in Lua Script

Tags: logging, lua, nosql, redis

I am writing a simple Lua Script for my Redis DB, and I want to use conditional logging, beacouse logs I use contain some string concatenation, and I would like to spare additional computations for Redis, if it's not absolutely needed. I have not found anything in Redis Lua script documentation, that can help me with this.

Does any body know how to get current log level in Redis Lua script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but not extremely convenient.

You can use the "config get loglevel" redis command to get the value of the parameter from the script.

For example:

```
EVAL "local tracelvl={debug=0,verbose=1,notice=2,warning=3};
      local trace=tracelvl[redis.call('config','get','loglevel')[2]];
      ...
      if trace>=redis.LOG_NOTICE then redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE,'hi there'); end ;
      ...
      if trace>=redis.LOG_WARNING then redis.log(redis.LOG_WARNING,'more important stuff'); end ;
" 0
```

If you have a large script with plenty of traces it could be useful (but is it a good idea to have large scripts with Redis? I don't think so).

If you just have one trace, the cost of the extra redis.call will probably be higher than string concatenation.